# Can't change M7000 front shifter from 2x into 3x

Tags: shimano, shifter, shifting

I bought exactly [this](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/shimano-slx-2-3x10-speed-sl-m7000-i-spec-ii-shift-lever-set-532725) set of shifters, latest SLX model.

I had similar SLX shifters, just the older ones, where the front one had a little button so it was easy to change from 2x to 3x.

Now this new one has nothing on the bottom or at the top, I do not see any kind of hint on the internet, how the hell can I change this shifter to 3x?

[Here](http://si.shimano.com/#/en/search/Keyword?name=SL-M7000) is all the info Shimano provides, but there is NOT a SINGLE WORD about switching into 3x mode.

This is a hilariously minor problem, which still cause a pretty big trouble to me.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Shimano's current documentation](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/slx-m7000.html#cg3SHICShiftLever) there are separate 2x and 3x specific shifters, not a single model that can be configured either way. The web-site you linked to appears to be misleading on this point as it implies the shifters can work for both 2x and 3x.

Find the exact product codes of what you received and check against the Shimano page. If you have the 2x specific shifters, return them.